# What is the name of this derivative property?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I think this is a derivative property but I forgot its name, it is involves derivative being multiplied.  I usually use it alot but I forget its name, and now I have a proof to do and do not know what to call this property.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: The chain rule.

Comment: Rule of differentiation for function composition is a nice name if you want to view differentiation as operations on functions and not just variables. But yes the chain rule is a more common name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is called chain rule.

If f is a function of x and g is a function of t,  ( I.e $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(t)$) ,then $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx} \boldsymbol{.} \frac{dx}{dt}$

Answer (score 0):

This is the chain rule which is similar to multiple representations as $\frac{d}{dx}$$(f(g(x))$=$f'(g(x))$$\cdot$$g'(x)$.

Comment: Here you made a mistake.$$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x)).g'(x)$$ and not $g(x)$

Comment: @NamasivayamKalithasan Thanks I missed the prime thing in $g(x)$